# Why does my ASP.NET web application not add a new user to my Azure Table storage?

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have created a new web-application in *Visual* *Studio* *2015* that begins by asking  a new user to register for a new account. The user completes their details via a Windows Form and then I have an *Azure* Cloud Service (including a web role featuring a WCF web-service) which is consumed and aims to update a remote *Azure* Table storage.

The problem I'm having is when the user submits the form the HTTP response code (retrieved using the *Fiddler* Web Debugger) is 200 success but nothing is created/added to the *Azure* Table Storage account. I am not a C# developer and web-services/*Azure* are both new to me so highly likely my code/configuration is flawed.

**RegisterUserService.svc.cs:**

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WCFServiceWebRoleRegisterUser
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class RegisterUserService : IRegisterService
    {
        public void AddNewUser(UserEntity user)
        {
            try
            {
            // Retrieve the storage account from the connection string.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting
                 ("registerCloudService40083714"));

            // Create the table client.
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

            // Create the table if it doesn't exist.
            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("users");
            table.CreateIfNotExists();

            // Create a new user entity.
            UserEntity newUserEntry = new UserEntity(user.Surname, user.Email);
            newUserEntry.Forename = user.Forename;
            newUserEntry.Password = user.Password;

            // Create the TableOperation object that inserts the user entity.
            TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(newUserEntry);

            // Execute the insert operation.
            table.Execute(insertOperation);

            if (table.Execute(insertOperation).HttpStatusCode == 403 ||
                table.Execute(insertOperation).HttpStatusCode == 409)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Account already registered with that Email Address");
            }
            else if (table.Execute(insertOperation) != null &&
                table.Execute(insertOperation).HttpStatusCode == 200)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Account successfully registered");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

**Register.aspx.cs:** (this is the code that consumes the WCF Cloud service)

```
using _40083714webapp.RegisterUserServiceReference;
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace _40083714webapp
{
    public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.UnobtrusiveValidationMode = UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;
        }

        protected void registerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterServiceClient client = new RegisterServiceClient();
            client.Open();
            UserEntity user = new UserEntity(surnameTextBox.ToString(), 
              emailTextBox.ToString());
            user.Password = passwordTextBox.ToString();
            user.Forename = forenameTextBox.ToString();
            // client.AddNewUser(user);
            client.AddNewUserAsync(user);
            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**IRegisterService.cs:**

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WCFServiceWebRoleRegisterUser
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRegisterService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void AddNewUser(UserEntity user);
    }
}
```

**UserEntity.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace WCFServiceWebRoleRegisterUser
{
    public class UserEntity : TableEntity
    {
        public UserEntity(string surname, string email)
        {
            this.PartitionKey = surname;
            this.RowKey = email;
        }

        public UserEntity() { }

        public string Forename { get; set; }

        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things I noticed in your code. Please take a look at them:

1. Assuming `client.AddNewUserAsync(user);` is an `async` operation, you may want to await on that. So your code would be:

   await client.AddNewUserAsync(user);
2. As a result of that, you would need to make `registerButton_Click` method `async`.
3. One thing I don't understand is why you're executing insert operation so many times in your `AddNewUser` code. Ideally you should execute this operation just once and capture the storage exception and do all the error handling there.

   ```
       // Execute the insert operation.
       table.Execute(insertOperation);//Wrap this in its own try/catch block and catch and handle StorageException type Exception.
       //This piece of code is not really needed.
       /*
       if (table.Execute(insertOperation).HttpStatusCode == 403 ||
           table.Execute(insertOperation).HttpStatusCode == 409)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine("Account already registered with that Email Address");
       }
       else if (table.Execute(insertOperation) != null &&
           table.Execute(insertOperation).HttpStatusCode == 200)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine("Account successfully registered");
       }
       */
   ```

Comment: thanks for your advice. (1) no, as can be seen in RegisterUserService.svc.cs, the AddNewUserAsync(user) method is not an async operation, I just changed this line from AddNewUser(user) as I thought the update was not being given enough time to complete before client.close(); was executed. following your advice I have completed (2) and (3) I agree that this is wrong I was trying various things. Now, however, I am receiving a new error:

Comment: An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it.

Comment: this problem is now resolved, I'm not entirely sure how but entities are now being added to the table. Although this answer didn't resolve the issue it was helpful and so I've accepted the answer. Cheers.